# remove div for same prefix id

Tags: jquery, html

There's a task i want to do, remove the divs with the same prefix.

```
<div id="random-asadf12s"></div>
<div id="random-afsdf123"></div>
<div id="random-xcvsd121"></div>
<div id="random-1edffxcx"></div>
<div id="random-56hgrgry"></div>
<div id="random-546fgfgh"></div>
<div id="random-gfh754yy"></div>
<div id="random-fghfghrt"></div>
```

those divs are generated by some js.

In jQuery, i can use `jQuery("#id").remove();` to remove a certain element. but how can i do the same thing if i don't know the exact id of the element?

Comment: In your js function, can you include a "name" attribute that is consistent for all of these divs?  If so, you could then use this attribute to find/remove all of these divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [*attribute starts with selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^="random-"]').remove();
```

This is probably better as jQuery can directly pass this selector to `querySelectorAll` in the newer browsers (although I don't know if it actually does it).

Alternatively you can use the [*attribute contains prefix selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/):

```
$('div[id|="random"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
$divs = $('div[id|="random"]').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

Comment: Going to put that one in the ol' memory banks.  Could be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
 $('div[id*="random-"]')
```

or the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
 $('div[id^="random-"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$("[id^=random-]").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about filter?

> $('div').filter(function () { return
>   /^random-/.test(this.id); })

Answer (score 1):

You can use .filter() function (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VG5BP/):

```
(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("body > div").filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr('id').match(/^(random-)/);
        }).remove();
    });
})();
```

In place of "body > div" you add selector for elements you want to check and possibly delete some of them. Check fiddle, it works.